# How to copy selected columns from excel file to other excel file using c#

Tags: c#, using

I want to copy a selected column from  one excel file and paste that column to other excel file  using c#

Comment: https://www.google.co.uk/search?sourceid=navclient&aq=&oq=c%23+excel+copy+range+from+one+workbook+to+another&hl=en-GB&ie=UTF-8&rlz=1T4GGLS_en-GBGB562GB562&q=c%23+excel+copy+range+from+one+workbook+to+another&gs_l=hp..0.0i22i30l5.0.0.0.8040...........0.5cPAK_G2mJI Ask google and get your finger out and try to do some work on it first. Nothing comes for free in this world....

Answer (score 0):

Use [this](http://epplus.codeplex.com/) free library. It's very simple to open and create xslx files! (not "free" but LGPL)